# Reuse a generated .so shared library Android in a new project

Tags: android, android-ndk

What I have done till now was:

Put my old lib (libold.so) in jni folder, and create a Android.mk, with:

```
LOCAL_PATH :=$(call my-dir) 

include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_MODULE := libold 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libold.so 
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

After that, I run ndk-build and it creates a new folder /libs/armeabi with libold.so.

It seems fine but when I run it can find the method that I call. The solution is to change the name package for the same that I used before.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The native method implementations in the NDK library all contain the Java package name (like `Java_com_myapp_MyClass_MyMethod()`). Make sure that in the new project, the wrapping Java classes sit in the same package (`com.myapp` in the example).

Answer (score 1):

Your JNI_OnLoad routine in the native .so is set up for a specific Java package name for the methods it resolves. If you use a different package name on the class (or multiple classes) you resolve native methods from, the VM cannot locate the correct methods unless your JNI_OnLoad knows how to tell the difference and register its natives correctly.

How you correct that will depend on how you went about registering the natives in the first place, but it's possible (even if a little convoluted) to have your registration process determine which package the load is being done for and register the methods accordingly.

Comment: I dont know how was registering bcz was not me how mad the library. However i would like to change the package name and use a differente name...

Comment: If you do not have source code to rebuild the library, you must use the same java package name for the class that requires the library. You can still use a different APK package name, as long as the one class that uses native methods keeps the package name that agrees with the .so.

Comment: SO,no change using android.mk prebuilt ?? :s

Comment: @user1477414 that's right. Theoretically it's possible with a hex editor but not generally recommended and not simple in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly use the compiled library in New Project. For different package names the corresponding function signature inside your c file will change .

```
    JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_package_class(JNIEnv *d, jobject e, jstring f) { 
//inside function

    }
```

You need a jar which contains classes, from the project in which you complied the so file, to make call to native functions in so file in order to make it accessible to a new project.